# how to skip a duplicate node when creating nodes in Neo4j

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I have a list of email address i use to create nodes. However if one of those email address already exist I don't want to get a CATCH '....node already exist' error since this would kill the entire query and none of the nodes would be created. So I am using a MERGE then ON CREATE to check the existence on the email address before creating the node. Problem is I need to create a relationship with a second node so after the MERGE and ON CREATE I have to use a WITH....CREATE to create the relationship and here lies the problem... the WITH is not under the 'scope' of the ON CREATE so the CREATE (a)--[r]->(b) now tries to create the a node with the email address I skipped in the MERGE above...resulting in CATCH '...already exist...' error a trash my query. Here is my CYPHER:

```
 commons.session
      .run['tom@abc.com', 'tony@mymail.com',michael@gmail.com'] AS coll
        UNWIND coll AS invitee
        WITH DISTINCT invitee
        MERGE (i {email: invitee})
        ON CREATE
          SET i:Invitee
        WITH i,invitee
        CREATE (s:Person {email: 'xyz123@abc.com})-[r:INVITED]->(i)
        RETURN i.email AS emails, COUNT(r) AS invitees)
```

What I am expecting to return is a list of only the email addresses where a node and relationship was created. Basically I need to be in the 'scope' of the ON CREATE since the duplicate would have been skipped. Any help in making this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a lot of other errors in your query. So, even if your stated issue is fixed, there would still be errors. For example, `r`, `sponsorEmail`, and `inviteeEmails` are never defined. You need to correct your question to remove the other errors (or simply your query to isolate your main issue).

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE 2]

```
WITH [
  {email:'tom@abc.com', name:'tom'},
  {email:'tony@mymail.com', name:'tony'},
  {email:'michael@gmail.com', name:'mike'}] AS coll
MATCH (s:Person {email: 'me@aol.com'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[x:INVITED]->()
WITH s, coll, COUNT(x) AS orig_count
UNWIND coll AS invitee
WITH DISTINCT s, orig_count, invitee
OPTIONAL MATCH (i {email: invitee.email, name: invitee.name})
FOREACH(ignored IN CASE WHEN i IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  CREATE (s)-[r:INVITED]->(:Invitee {email: invitee.email, name: invitee.name})
)
WITH s, orig_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[x:INVITED]->()
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT x) - orig_count AS new_relationship_count
```

Explanation:

- The `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause will generate a `NULL` value for `i` if the node pattern is not found.
- `CASE WHEN i IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END` will return a non-empty list if and only if `i` is `NULL`.
- If the list is empty, then the `FOREACH` clause will not execute its contained write clause(s). Otherwise, it will execute all of them.
- At the beginning, this query first gets a count (`orig_count`) of the original number of `INVITED` relationships outgoing from `s`.
- At the end, it gets a final count and subtracts `orig_count` from that to get `new_relationship_count`.

Comment: @cybersam....I have edited the question for clarity. I am not sure I am clear on the answer!....are you creating the node and relationship IF there was a MATCH? Because I want to do the opposite....I will however test your answer.

Comment: @cybersam...The CREATE (s:Person {email:......) line failed with the constraint error so I retrieved that node with a MATCH statement just before the OPTIONAL MATCH and then use CREATE (s)-[INVITED]->(i) in the FOREACH(...) statement. This worked, however I cannot access any values (s,r,i) in the FOREACH block for my RETURN statement....I get undefined.  I need to know how many successful relationships were created OR how successful CREATE (i:Invitee {....}) were created

Comment: Can you update your question with an addendum that shows the actual query that you are using?

Comment: @cybersam.....Your edit is the same change I made...however the main problem is that FOREACH won't allow access to the 'result' of the queries/mutations within the FOREACH block so for my purposes I can't use FOREACH....I am trying to rework the UNWIND with the OPTIONAL MATCH and the CASE statement to see if that would work...nothing yet.

Comment: @cybersam...Nope....that would just be the count (which I am not sure is reliable). The result of the CREATE in the FOREACH block ...the r.property and Invitee properties are not available....maybe I should point out the reason I am doing this is to get the email addresses of those node created so I can send notification type email......I will keep working and will post my solution when done.

Comment: In previous comment, you stated: "I need to know how many successful relationships were created OR ...". My updated answer satisfies that requirement, and does return a reliable count (unless other queries are adding/deleting such relationships concurrently). Have you determined what you actually want as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so the neither FOREACH nor CASE did the trick. Actually the WHERE clause did. My original need as stated in the question was to accept a list of emails, create nodes where a node doesn't exist for an email in the list and return a list of the created emails nodes and a count of how many....AND didn't fail on an 'email already exist...' error CATCH statement.This is the solution I mustered:

```
MATCH(s:Person {email: 'mike@gmailxxx.com'})
WITH s, ['abcd123@abc.com','abcd123@abc.com','abcd456@abc.com','michael@abc.com'] AS coll
   UNWIND coll AS invitee
   WITH DISTINCT invitee, s
    OPTIONAL MATCH (i {email: invitee})
    WITH s,invitee, i
     WHERE i IS NULL
      CREATE (s)-[r:INVITED]->(n:Invitee {email:invitee})
  RETURN s,n, COUNT(r)
```

With the WHERE clause I was able to focus on only those emails for which there were no nodes already created.

Thanks to @cybersam for his suggestion of the OPTIONAL MATCH and his iterations for a possible solution.